# Which set is this 2017 bag 3 with dark red and grey pieces from?

Tags: set-identification

I'm trying to find out what set this is from.  I'm having a really hard time looking this up QR code 6171967.

[image]

Comment: The info on the bag is about the bag itself and isn't specific to the kit it came in. the 2017 refers to the bag design.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the minifig torso and the selection of pieces in the bag I believe you have bag 3 from set [76104 The Hulkbuster Smash-Up](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76104-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from 2018.

[image]